# Given a set of ids, remove all documents with those ids

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to remove a set of ids using an object which contains those ids. Right now I am iteratively removing ti. Is it possible to remove them at once?

My code (iteratively):

```
remove_data(doc[0]._id,function(result){
    for(entry in result) {
        db.mydata.remove({"_id":result[entry]}, function(err,doc) {
            if(err) throw err;            
        });
    }
});
```

Also I need to pass a callback after this is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First combine IDs into a list:

```
var ids = [];
for (var k in result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        ids.push(result[k]);
    }
};
```

and then

```
db.mydata.remove({"_id": {"$in": ids}}, function(err) {
    // ...
});
```

Side note: if you are dealing with multiple asynchronous tasks and you have to call a callback after all of them finish then you should use some kind of *asynchronous control flow library*. Caolan's async.js is a good choice:

https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: I did that but it says Object has no method append.

Comment: @wannaC Oops, sorry. It should've been `.push`. Too much Python lately. :)